# Accessing a Kubernetes service using nodePort from external load balancer

Tags: load-balancing, kubernetes

When I expose the kubernetes service using nodePort , then I can access the port/service using any workder node IP:PORT , even if the service is just actually running on just one node.

What would be the recommended way of accessing the service from an external load balancer where session persistence is required , should I just dynamically discover the extact node on which the service is running so that the kube proxy can proxy it to local node port , OR accessing the service on all the nodes from the external load balancer will still be OK , and serve the same purpose without causing any issue?

Update:  we have many options of enabling sesson afinity on the external load balancer level , the qesution is:

- will it work without any probem, with nodeport as the backend, on all the nodes
- Or nodeport on just the node/nodes on which the pod is actually running

Comment: I can't offer a comprehensive solution, but here are some things I found. IP-based session affinity can be enabled on the service definition using the `service.spec.sessionAffinity` element. If you need something more advanced, you might need to use an ingress controller.

Comment: we have many options of enabling sesson afinity on the external load balancer , the qesution is , will it work without any probem with nodeport as the backend on all the nodes or just the node on which the pod is actually running

Comment: I doubt if that configuration would work. The only session affinity that can be specified with a nodePort service is ClientIP. If you then use an external load balancer, then the service will only the see the load balancer's IP. That will send all of your requests to a single pod. If you don't specify the session affinity on the service, your requests will be distributed to all the pods, and that will break your sessions.

Comment: Ok , so maybe ,  I need to configure the service to server all the requests from local pod on each node, and then in the external load balancer , I send the traffic to selected worker nodes on which those pods are running. and keep discovering thoese nodes so that if the pods migrate to other node , the external loadbalancer gets updated automatically.

Comment: You can also consider deploying an ingress controller as a more straightforward alternative. The nginx ingress controller offers session persistence, according to the docs.